# How to retrieve the email ID from firebase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

**My login page**

```
class _MyLoginState extends State<MyLogin> {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //editing controller
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  int _success = 1 ;
  late String _userEmail = "";

  void _signIn() async {
    final User? user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
    ).user;

    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        _success = 2;
        _userEmail = user.email!;
      });
    }else {
      setState(() {
        _success = 3;
      });
    }
  }
```

**My profile screen for a user**

```
class _UserAccState extends State<UserAcc> {


  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late String userEmail;
  void getCurrentUserEmail() async {
    final user =
    _auth.currentUser().then((value) => userEmail = value.email);
  }

  late final TextEditingController emailController;
```

The code in UserAcc that i have posted, will it retrieve the email id from firebase? If not, tell me how to do it. I'm a beginner at flutter.
I'm very much confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is very close to being correct, but to get the Email, you must use a function which actually returns a value (String in this case).

Right now you are setting the 'user' variable to the email, but it has not been returned.

Comment: I have used the function getCurrentUserEmail() but I haven't returned it. Or do I have to enclose the whole code in a function?

Comment: In this void, you have not returned anything (which you also cannot in a void, but as you did, you are trying to set userEmail to value.email).
You could use a function instead, and in that function, you should return the email. Since you have an async you would need a future.

But it also depends on what you precisely want to do. If you want a block of code, which sets userEmail equal to the value.email, then you can use setState around your current code. setstate around userEmail = value.email.

But if you want to get the email, you can also try _auth.currentUser!.email

Comment: Is this correct? If not, can you do the correction?

` final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late String userEmail;
  Future getCurrentUserEmail() async {
    final user =
    _auth.currentUser!.then((value) {
      setState(() => userEmail = value.email);
    });
  }`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry was moving IRL, yes that should work. Just make sure that you userEmail is at a state where it can be called outside of the function (which it does look like it is here) (you do that by declaring it outside of the function and just change the value inside the function)